# ROS Answers SE migration: Custom message

Tags: ros-kinetic, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have defined this custom message, FloatsStamped.msg :

```
Header header
float32[] data
```

The CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(grideye)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(
  FILES
  FloatsStamped.msg
)

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################

catkin_package(
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

My package.xml is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <name>grideye</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The grideye package</description>

  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <build_depend>python-numpy</build_depend>
  <run_depend>python-numpy</run_depend>

</package>
```

And finally the code I use is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import numpy
from grideye.msg import FloatsStamped
from grideye_class import GridEye
    
def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('thermal_pixels', FloatsStamped, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('grideye', anonymous=True)
    r = rospy.Rate(5)
    pix = []
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        pix = mysensor.getPixels()
        print(pix)

        #feed a FloatsStamped msg
        a = FloatsStamped
        a.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now() 
        a.data = numpy.array(pix, dtype=numpy.float32)

        pub.publish(a)
        r.sleep()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mysensor = GridEye()
    rospy.loginfo("Starting data retrieving from Grid Eye sensor Board")
    talker()
```

I get an error message indicating that :

> ```
> a.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()  AttributeError: 'member_descriptor'
> ```
>
> object has no attribute 'stamp'

I declare `a` as FloatsStamped message and this message includes the Header message, so I don't understand why I get this error message.

matt

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283413/custom-message/) by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-02-22**:
Try `a = FloatsStamped()`, with the trailing parentheses.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-23**:
@Thomas D comment should really be an answer, as it is most likely *the* answer.

@mattMGN: you are assigning to `a` the *type* of `FloatStamped` (ie: the class), *not* to an instance of it (ie: an object). `data` is not a field of the class, but of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `a = FloatsStamped()`, with the trailing parentheses.

As @gvdhoorn points out in a comment: you are assigning to `a` the type of `FloatStamped` (ie: the class), *not* to an instance of it (ie: an object). `data` is not a field of the class, but of the object.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2018-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mattMGN](https://answers.ros.org/users/29874/mattmgn/) on 2018-02-27**:
You are right, It now works
Thanks for your comment